Как поменять спрайт кнопки, при нажатии на другую кнопку Unity?
Я начинающий разработчик игр на Unity, сейчас создаю 2д кликер и у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, менялся спрайт кнопки "клик"(то есть скин кнопки) после чего всё сохранялось. Все объекты находятся на одной сцене. Уже долго мучаюсь с этим, помогите, пожалуйста!


